# Node JS CPU Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an issue on a production application sometimes using 100% of CPU .
My NodeJS version is v5.11.1

I was wondering what could be using this issue and how to solve that. So I used node-module "v8-profiler" to get some logs. I loaded this file into profile tab of the Google Chrome Dev Tools and I can see that 97% of the time is spent in a hash method of express-session but this does not tell me where and what could be reason of this.

A link to this logfile [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21469150/profile0.cpuprofile).

I would like ideas to know first if this is coming from my application or could be coming from one of node-module I'm using.

Thanks in advance for any help.

My package json is:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
    "assert": "^1.4.0",
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "bundalo": "^0.2.10",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "csv": "^0.4.6",
    "csv-stringify": "1.0.4",
    "date-utils": "^1.2.21",
    "dust-makara-helpers": "^4.1.2",
    "dustjs-helpers": "^1.7.3",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "^2.7.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-bcp47": "^3.0.3",
    "express-csv": "^0.6.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "forms": "^1.1.3",
    "json2csv": "^3.4.2",
    "kraken-devtools": "^1.2.3",
    "kraken-js": "^2.1.0",
    "localize": "^0.4.7",
    "localizr": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "lusca": "^1.4.1",
    "makara": "^2.0.3",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.19",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "nconf": "~0.8.4",
    "node-forge": "^0.6.39",
    "oauth2orize": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-http": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-oauth2-client-password": "^0.1.2",
    "plist": "^1.2.0",
    "request": "^2.69",
    "temp": "^0.8.3",
    "winston": "^2.2.0",
    "winston-syslog": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.3.0",
    "chai": "^1.10.0",
    "faker": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-config-dir": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-copy-to": "0.0.10",
    "grunt-dustjs": "^1.4.0",
    "grunt-mocha-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "mocha": "^2.1.0",
    "supertest": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "generator-kraken": {
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "template": "dustjs",
    "css": false,
    "js": false,
    "task": "grunt"
  }
}
```

Comment: of all the files in your node app, package.json is guaranteed to NOT cause the issue you describe. Consider posting your *code* if you want help

Comment: @JaromandaX This is one thousand files application, I can not share all the code. As I said, I do not know from which specific line / file it's coming from. My post is to try to find cause of the issue...

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As @JaromandaX said, your package.json is definitely not the problem, and we can't help you without code.

Answer (score 1):

most of the libraries are reputable libraries, i believe its something in your code not in your requires. you might want to do profiling to see where the cause is.

## node memory profiling

this is a long topic, yet easy to apply, there are plenty of tutorials out there, i can suggest a few aswell.

- use `v8-profile`: here is an awesome tutorial: https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my link to logfile was done with v8 profile.